# javascript equivalent of PHP string append

Tags: php, javascript, string

in php, i do this to connect strings

(pseudo code)

```
$myString = "";
for($i = 0;$i < 10;$i++)
    $myString .= $i;
echo $myString;
```

would give me 0123456789

you got the idea
,now, how can i do the same in javascript?

Comment: JS string concatenate symbol is a +

Comment: Is that an answer Shehzad? you accidentally put it in the comments box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript uses the plus sign for string concatenation. So:

```
mystring = 'this' + 'that';   //gives string value "thisthat"
```

It is important to note that Javascript also uses the plus sign for numeric addition. This means that you can get into trouble with variable types.

```
var myInt = 5;
var myString = "5";

alert(myInt + 5);     //gives the string value "55".
alert(myString + 5);  //gives the integer value 10.
```

This means that your PHP trick of adding numbers together to make string, as per your question, will only work if you start with a string variable. PHP can recognise for itself that you intend it to be a string operation because of the concat operator; Javascript doesn't have that ability, so you have to tell it explicity by making sure that your variables are of the correct type.

Answer (score 3):

```
var myString = "";
for(var i = 0;i < 10;i++)
    myString += i;
alert(myString);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the += operator.

So in pseudo code your code should be something like

```
myString = "";
for(i = 0;i < 10;i++)
    myString += i;
alert(myString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it will do it.

```
var $myString = "";
    for(var $i = 0;$i < 10;$i++){
        $myString += $i;//+=  the equivalent of .= in JS
}
    alert( $myString );
```